# How can I search several elements in python list?

Tags: python, list

I want to write a program to find how many `[a,b,c]` in `[a,a, b,c,d,a,a,b,c,c,d,d,d]`.

The answer that I want is 2.

There are four `a's` in the list, but `b` is 2, and `c` is 3.
So I want to get a minimum number of `[a,b,c]`

Comment: check how many of each are there, there's lots of answers on how to do that. Then write one additional logic step to get the minimum. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried so far.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry that I'm the beginner of Python, and this is my first question in this website. I don't understand the rules yet, but I'll try to follow them from now on. Thank you all for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one approach:

```
l = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','c','d','d','d']
seq = ['a','b','c']

sum(1 for i in range(len(l) - len(seq)-1) if l[i: i + len(seq)] == seq)
# 2
```

---

Where on each iteration we are comparing a slice or *window* of `l` with `seq` and returning `1` if they are equal. Hence this produces the following slices:

```
[l[i: i + len(seq)] for i in range(len(l) - len(seq)-1)]

[['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c', 'd'],
 ['c', 'd', 'a'],
 ['d', 'a', 'a'],
 ['a', 'a', 'b'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['b', 'c', 'c'],
 ['c', 'c', 'd']]
```

---

Or we could also use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) to convert both lists to strings and then use [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html):

```
''.join(l).count(''.join(seq))
# 2
```

Comment: quite interesting approach I must say :) +1. But is it efficient enough then say, using counter? @yatu

Comment: Hmm i guess the first thing that came into my mind is to approach this with a sliding window over the lsit :) returned @DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: this looks like answer to a different question than OP was asking who just wants counts not counts of subsequence, admittedly I interpreted it this way also (hence the +1)

Comment: Duh didn't notice @AndrewAllen, thanks for pointing out and for the upvote :)

Answer (score 3):

```
abc = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
min([abc.count(i) for i in  ['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this.

The idea is to calculate the counts of all elements in the list, and take the minimum count of keys `a,b,c`

```
from collections import Counter
l = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','c','d','d','d']
seq = ['a','b','c']

#Create counter of list
c = Counter(l)
#{'d': 4, 'a': 3, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}
#Take minimum count from counts of keys a,b and c
result = min([c[key] for key in seq])
print(result)
```

The result will be `2`

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> l = ['a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','c','d','d','d']
>>> counter = Counter(l)
>>> 
>>> min(counter['a'], counter['b'], counter['c'])
2
```

Answer (score 0):

main a dictionary to keep the frequency of occurrence of each character

```
from collections import defaultdict
dic=defaultdict(int)
l=[a,a, b,c,d,a,a,b,c,c,d,d,d]
seq=[a,b,c]

for i in l:
    dic[i]+=1

sol = min([dic[i] for i in seq])

print(sol)
```

Answer (score 0):

c = ['a','b','c'] 
cc = ['a','a','b','c','d','a','a','b','c','c','d','d','d']

```
result = {}
for i in c:
    res = cc.count(i)
    chec_res = {i:res}
    result.update(chec_res)

Min_val = min(result.keys(), key=(lambda m: result[m]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats one easy way to do it :
abc = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd']
min([abc.count(i) for i in  ['a', 'b', 'c']])